# html_entity_decode not working properly

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, html-entities

I'm using html_entity_decode to decode html codes, and then using preg_replace, but for some reason it's replacing all my single quotes for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

$userResponse = "I&#039;m tired.";
$userResponse = html_entity_decode($userResponse); //make codes like &#039; into '
$userResponse = preg_replace("~[^*a-zA-Z,.!?' ]~", "", $userResponse);
echo $userResponse;

?>
```

**Result:**  Im tired.

**Expected Result:**  I'm tired.

Comment: Have you checked `$userResponse` after `html_entity_decode()`ing it? On CLI I still get `"I&#039;m tired."` Had to `$userResponse =html_entity_decode($userResponse, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8');` to fix it

Comment: You do realize that you're stripping the apostrophe specifically?

Comment: @kerbholz Yeah, I added your code and it works. Yeah, I don't know why it didn't turn &#039; into ' with the regular html_entity_decode.

Comment: @mario Well, not really. This is a user input variable, so I'm stripping everything that's not excluded in the preg_replace.